# Rachni in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

I saved the Rachni in ME1, so now in ME3 I have to kill them on a frequent basis.

I'm just wondering, what would happen if I would have killed them? Would they still be there, or replaced by another ennemy? Also, if they are still there, what is the explanation why this species you made extinct yourself in still running around?

For those who wouldn't know what a rachni look like, [Heres what it looks like.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rachni)

And I'm fighting them

> Right in the Ancient City of the Krogan, on Tuchanka.

Comment: What, you have to fight them?  But the queen and I were buds :(

Comment: You still are. And why they are attacking is spoilerish.

Comment: Yes, they are still there, and being already friends with the queen could be helpful in the future. They aren't ordinary rachni, but you should already be able to see that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually seems saving the Queen in ME1 and then again in 3, will be more beneficial to Shepard.

> If Shepard did not spare the Rachni queen on Noveria, the Reapers will artificially construct a Queen thrall in order to control a rachni army. Shepard can choose to spare this artificial queen even if the Commander killed the real queen. This queen will eventually betray Shepard, taking the Rachni Workers War Assets away and decreasing the numerical values of some Alliance fleet War Assets.

As with all "plot" characters that die, they do get some form of replacement, it just so happens her replacement is much more sinister.

---

[**source**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rachni#Mass_Effect_3)

Personally, I saved the Queen, which, losing the Krogans sucked ('cept for Grunt's general awesomeness), provided a ton of War Assets added to the cause.

Comment: I still got War Assets for their squad though, but it might not have been as high as if I'd saved them instead of the queen.

Comment: Same here, I would assume that as well.

Comment: Still, I think saving the queen nets a higher War Assets award than sacrificing her.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If anyone has numbers on the how many war assets the squad is worth if you save them for comparison's sake, that'd be great!

Comment: I saved the squad and its worth 75 points.

Comment: If you save the queen (in me 1 & 3) you get a total of 175 war assests with the addition Grunt's 25 (he doesn't die ether way if he was loyal in 2) if you let the queen die you just get Arlakh Company and you only get 100, so you lose about 75 assests by killing her the second time.